Change app name in Pixel Launcher
There are several apps that I would like to rename in the app launcher. For example, I have the Google "Calc" app, and another calculator app with more features that is named "Calc" and has a similar icon. I'd like to rename the app with more features to maybe "Fancy Calc" for example. Another possible use I would do is to prefix all Google apps with "G " to easily group all Google apps in the alphabetical lists together.
I have the Pixel 8 Pro phone.
